Build not working due to quarenteeded dependency but dependency doesn't appear in maven tree
A maven build is failing at my workplace. It is attempting to download log4j-1.2.12, however this library is quarantined due to a security vulnerability. I am trying to replace it with log4j-2.17.1, which is not quarantined.
However I am unable to located what dependency or transitive dependency is calling this library to override it with log4j-2.17.1. As when calling the maven job mvn dependency:tree, log4j-1.2.12 does not appear as a dependency or transitive dependency.
I tried adding log4j-2.17.1 to the dependency tree, and trying to find what is requested log4j-1.2.12 to override it but unable to determine that with the dependency:tree maven goal. I tried a clean maven goal, error still occured.

Have you updated all your plugins to the most recent versions.... ? Also the Maven version itself?
